# How to change the database schema in config.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, configuration-files

I'm working in finished application build with Node.js + Express.js.

**I can't change the database configurations** because other modules use the default configuration in `config.js`.

But, I need change the **schema** of this database just in certain locations.

How can I do that?

Old query example:

```
var query = "select * from " + config.bd.schema + ".user_types ;";
```

New query (I need to use the `dash` scheme)

```
var query = "select * from dash.user_types ;";
```

---

### The code

```
getData: function(params, callback) {

  var response = {
    general: null
  };

  var query = "select column_1, column_2, column_3 from dash.user_types";

  if(params.column_3 && params.column_3 != "") {
    query += " where column_3 = " + params.column_3 + "";
  } else {
    query += "";
  }

  util.bdConnect(function(client,done) {
    client.query(query,function(err,result) {
      if(err) throw err; // LINE 69
      done();

      response.general = result.rows;

      callback(null, mountReport(response.general));
    });
  });
},
```

### The application error when I pass schema manually

```
Report.js - getData() >>> column_3 >>>  select column_1, column_2, column_3 from dash.general_report where column_3 = 777
/home/patrick/Workspace/company/project/admin/proj/models/Report.js:69
        if(err) throw err;
                ^

error: syntax error at or near "select"
    at Connection.parseE (/home/patrick/Workspace/company/project/admin/proj/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:534:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/home/patrick/Workspace/company/project/admin/proj/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:361:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/patrick/Workspace/company/project/admin/proj/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:105:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:523:20)
```

### Info

When I get the query and put in my `psql`, does not return any error.

---

If you need more information, tell me before down vote.

*Sorry for my english*

Comment: are you changing the schema or getting it (querying) using `select query`?

Comment: I change the schema only in the `query` variable, because I can't change in `config.js` (other modules use the default schema). When I do that (pass manually the schema in query),  the application return an error.

Comment: @Maxali I put the error in my question.

Comment: Error appears to be a syntax error. Can you post the actual code around Report.js line 69? it could be that you are querying something like "select * from .user_types;" because some variable is empty

Comment: @chriskelly I'm doing that right now, but not work: `var query = "select * from dash.user_types ;"`

Comment: ok, but can you put code in the question. The error says syntax error.  There is no syntax error in what you just typed

Comment: @chriskelly I update the question and add the code.

Comment: have you tried printing the query string before util.bdConnect?

Comment: @chriskelly not yet. I'll try now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101081/discussion-between-patrick-maciel-and-chriskelly).

Comment: var query = "select column_1, column_2, column_3 dash.user_types" - where is the FROM clouse?

Comment: @LucasCosta my mistake when I edit the code in SO. It's correct in my file.

Answer (score 0):

**My mistake guys...**

I not post the original query for security reasons but...
In the original query I have a column with the character `é` (accent). Wrong right?

I didn't see that in editor and when I checked the that, it was wrong too.

So I rename the column, fix the query and done. Works.

Thanks for help and sorry :(

*Obs.: I did not create this database*

Comment: Oh dear. I actually noticed that character but assumed it was just fine. In English I never ever have use for accents so I assume they just work in languages where they are needed. Lesson learned!~

Comment: Yes @chriskelly. Because that when I'm the responsible for administrate the database, I always create in english: table names and columns. Anyway, thank you for your time :)

Comment: np. glad you figured it out and glad to  have learned somethign too